# Overwriting an error in jQuery Validate

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I've been able to use the [remote](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/) method for [jQuery Validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) when defining rules to include an Ajax call for checking whether an email is in use. If an email is already in the database the `messages` option contains the html for the error label that appears:

```
messages: {
    email: {
        remote: "<button type='button' id='load_details'>Load</button> this users details?"
    }
}
```

Next I set up a function where on click of this button the necessary user details fill the form. Once this has happened the error needs to be removed.

```
$.ajax({
    // ajax call
    ...
    success: function (data) {
        // update necessary fields
        $('#first_name').val(data.first_name);
        $('#last_name').val(data.last_name);
        $('#phone').val(data.phone);

        var validator = $('#addProduct_form').validate(); // access the validator
        var element = $('#email');                        // store the element
        validator.settings.success(element);              // something to overwrite the error

        // undo the error placement
        $('#email').parent().removeClass('error-control');
        $('label[for="email"].error').hide();
    }
});
```

Although this removes the error visually it is not a solution. I make use of the `invalidHandler` option to set up a test on form submit that is still triggered because of this error.

```
invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
    var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
    if (errors) {
        var message = errors == 1
            ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted'
            : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields. They have been highlighted';
        $("div.error span").html(message);
        $("div.error").show();
    } else {
        $("div.error").hide();
    }
},
```

Thus the form will not submit and the error simply shows again. Further more if a user is to ever click the field again, regardless of them actually changing anything, the error re-displays.

Is there an elegant solution so that on clicking the button the error is removed/overwritten? Something that isn't just a way around my invalidHandler function? Something that overwrites the error should solve the problem of submitting and of re-clicking the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to make use of a variable to check whether to apply the rule, so structure can be something like

```
jQuery(function($) {
  var dataloaded = false;

  jQuery('#addProduct_form').validate({
    rules: {
      email: {
        remote: {
          param: {
              //your ajax settings
          },
          depends: function() {
            return !dataloaded;
          }
        }
      }
    },
    messages: {
      email: {
        remote: "<button type='button' id='load_details'>Load</button> this users details?"
      }
    }
  });

  jQuery('#addProduct_form').on('click', '#load_details', function() {
    //do the ajax request here and on success set 

    dataloaded = true;
    $('#email').valid();
  });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/avbmuowz/)

---

Another is to remove the rule itself like

```
  jQuery('#addProduct_form').on('click', '#load_details', function() {
    //do the ajax request here and on success set 

    $('#email').rules('remove','remote');
    $('#email').valid();
  });
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e5xuonL9/)

Comment: Thank you! I had been looking for this sort of thing in the documentation but obviously wasn't searching the right stuff. Your first suggestion worked as I had hoped. Many thanks!